# Why update a table several times that has new rows causes the exception of concurrent access with sqlite in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I want to update a table several times. If I create a new row in this table, it causes an exception of concurrent access in the second update.

For example, for the table:

```
TABLE `TableTest1` {  
    `Id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE  
    `Entier`    INTEGER  
    `Texte` TEXT  
    `Reel`  REAL  
    `Numerique` NUMERIC  
    `BLOB`  BLOB
}
```

this code is ok:

```
TestBase1DataSet.TableTest1Row ttr;
ttr = testBase1DataSet.TableTest1[0];
ttr.Texte = "Old text";
tableTest1TableAdapter.Update(testBase1DataSet);
ttr.Texte = "New text";
tableTest1TableAdapter.Update(testBase1DataSet);
```

because the row 0 of `TableTest1` already exists.

This code causes the exception of concurrent access:

```
TestBase1DataSet.TableTest1Row ttr;

ttr = testBase1DataSet.TableTest1.NewTableTest1Row(); 
testBase1DataSet.TableTest1.AddTableTest1Row(ttr);

ttr.Texte = "Old text";
tableTest1TableAdapter.Update(testBase1DataSet);

ttr.Texte = "New text";
tableTest1TableAdapter.Update(testBase1DataSet);
```

Why does this happen, and how to avoid exception?

Best regards

Comment: After you update the first time, your local datarow doesnt not match the data in the db - it lacks the PK supplied by the DB, but the RowState is changed.  If you change the same row object, it will try to UPDATE but it cannot find a row with the matching ID of DbNull.

Comment: How to not have this exception? The only solution I found is to redo a fill after the first update , search for the row to edit and do another update . But if the DB is huge , it can be take a long time . Are you there another solution?

thank you,

Comment: ...or you could skip the first update, make *all* the changes and update once.  Generally using a properly set up adapter, a fill will only get the new/changed rows; that is, it is a refresh.

Comment: Good answer. Thank a lot.